# Помогите переделать класс на С++\СLI

Tags: c++, c++-cli

Только начал разбираться с С++\CLI. Вот хочу сделать небольшой класс. Начал уже переделывать, но не вышло. Компилятор ругается на массив name. Я понимаю, что при работе в СLI массив объявляется не так, но сделать правильно не могу. Помогите поправить.

```
  ref class Theacher 
 {
  private:
          char name[10];
          int year;
  public:

    void SetData(char *d_name, const int &d_year)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<strlen(d_name); i++)
        {
            name[i] = d_name[i];
        }
        year = d_year;
    }

    int Working()
    {
        int result;
        result = 2016 - year;
        return result;
    }
    void GetData()
    {
        cout << "Name: ";
        for (int i=0; i<strlen(name); i++)
        {
            cout << name[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Working: " << Working() << endl;
    }
  };

   int main()
   {
     Theacher ^theacher = gcnew Theacher;

     char name[10];
     int year;

     cout << "Name: ";
     gets(name);
     cout << "Year: ";
     cin >> year;

     theacher -> SetData(name,year);
     theacher -> Working();
     theacher -> GetData();

     system("pause");
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

О боже, зачем вам этот ужас — C++/CLI? Намучаетесь вы с ним. Учите либо чистый C++, либо C#, если хотите освоить .NET.

Для вашего случая:

1. В .NET-приложениях не стоит без необходимости использовать `std::string`, не говоря уже о совершенно низкоуровневом `char*`. Используйте вместо этого `System::String^`.
2. Для вывода на консоль пользуйтесь не `cout`, а `Console::Write`.
3. Для работы со строками используйте высокоуровневые функции.
4. Даже в учебных примерах, никогда не пользуйтесь функцией `gets`.

Результат:

```
using namespace System;

ref class Teacher
{
private:
    String^ name;
    int year;
public:

    void SetData(String ^d_name, int d_year)
    {
        name = d_name;
        year = d_year;
    }

    int Working()
    {
        int result;
        result = 2016 - year;
        return result;
    }

    void GetData()
    {
        Console::Write("Name: ");
        Console::Write(name);
        Console::WriteLine();
        Console::WriteLine(String::Format("Working: {0}", Working()));
    }
};

int main()
{
    Teacher ^teacher = gcnew Teacher;

    Console::Write("Name: ");
    String ^name = Console::ReadLine();
    Console::Write("Year: ");
    int year = Convert::ToInt32(Console::ReadLine());

    teacher->SetData(name, year);
    teacher->Working();
    teacher->GetData();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. А в CLI ради интереса залез.

Comment: @SimonRaily: Пожалуйста! Но лучше всё же посмотрите на C#, на нём всё то же самое куда проще.